# list of 2000 random football players using from wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I tried to get 2000 random soccer players with additional information (name, team, team number, apperances, goals) from wikidata with this query:

```
SELECT ?SoccerPlayerLabel ?Teams ?TeamsLabel ?TeamNumber ?TeamNumberLabel ?Appearances ?AppearancesLabel ?Goals ?GoalsLabel  WHERE 
{?SoccerPlayer wdt:P106 wd:Q937857;
wdt:P54 ?Teams;
wdt:P1618 ?TeamNumber;
wdt:P1350 ?Appearances.
?SoccerPlayer wdt:P1351 ?Goals.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".}
}
LIMIT 2000
```

but I didn't get any results

Comment: if you look at a particular soccer player, you"ll see that number of matches and goals is not directly connected to each player but per career station, so you have to rewrite your query. You should start with learning the Wikidata data model and read about  statement qualifiers and the like. And rethink your variable naming

Comment: what you want is something like this:`SELECT ?SoccerPlayer ?SoccerPlayerLabel ?Team ?TeamLabel ?TeamNumber 
?numMatches ?numGoals  WHERE {
  ?SoccerPlayer wdt:P106 wd:Q937857;
p:P54 ?teamStmt .
  ?teamStmt ps:P54 ?Team;
pq:P1618 ?TeamNumber;
pq:P1350 ?numMatches;
pq:P1351 ?numGoals.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".}
}
LIMIT 20`

Comment: or more consice: `SELECT ?SoccerPlayer ?SoccerPlayerLabel ?Team ?TeamLabel ?TeamNumber 
?numMatches ?numGoals  WHERE {
  ?SoccerPlayer wdt:P106 wd:Q937857;
p:P54 [ ps:P54 ?Team;
pq:P1618 ?TeamNumber;
pq:P1350 ?numMatches;
pq:P1351 ?numGoals ].
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".}
}
LIMIT 20`

Comment: if you want only one row per player, you have to use grouping + aggregate functions (`group_concat` and `sum`) -

Comment: E.g. e.g. `SELECT ?SoccerPlayerLabel 
(group_concat(distinct ?TeamLabel;separator=", ") as ?teams)
(sum(?numMatches) as ?numMatchesTotal)
(sum(?numGoals) as ?numGoalsTotal)
{
SELECT ?SoccerPlayer ?SoccerPlayerLabel ?Team ?TeamLabel ?TeamNumber 
?numMatches ?numGoals  WHERE {
  ?SoccerPlayer wdt:P106 wd:Q937857;
p:P54 [ ps:P54 ?Team;
pq:P1618 ?TeamNumber;
pq:P1350 ?numMatches;
pq:P1351 ?numGoals ].
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".}
}LIMIT 20
}group by ?SoccerPlayerLabel`

Comment: @AKSW I used the last one and added a time limitation (?startTime >= "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z") to get recent teams but I had only 3 players, something must went wrong, here is my query:

Comment: SELECT?SoccerPlayerLabel(group_concat(distinct?TeamLabel;separator=", ")as?teams)(sum(?numMatches)as?numMatchesTotal)(sum(?numGoals) asnumGoalsTotal){SELECT?SoccerPlayer ?SoccerPlayerLabel ?Team ?TeamLabel?TeamNumber?numMatches?numGoals?startTimeWHERE{?SoccerPlayer wdt:P106 wd:Q937857; p:P54 [ ps:P54 ?Team; 
 pq:P1618 ?TeamNumber;
        pq:P1350 ?numMatches; 
        pq:P1351 ?numGoals;
        pq:P580 ?startTime];
FILTER(?startTime >= "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime).
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".} }}
group by ?SoccerPlayerLabel